# android, layout null pointer exception :: no clear reason

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.simonaddicott.controlpanel_1.numbers">

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/numberSearch"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:queryHint="@string/number_search_placeholder">
    </SearchView>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is giving me rendering problems NullPointerException. Why?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException   at
 android.content.res.TypedArray.hasValueOrEmpty(TypedArray.java:845)   at
 android.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:295)   at
 android.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:258)   at
 android.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:254)   at
 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)   at
 android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
```

I see no indication in the error report of a mistake in the xml, or anything that relates to my code. I read over the documentation on the android dev site, and i cannot see any mention of anything additional required.

Comment: Can you  show how did you declare "tools:context" attribute? I would assume that the problem is with it

Comment: That's just a rendering problem, but it would work fine if you run the app on device!